# Java - Format a double to currency, values under a dollar omitting the 0

Tags: java, double, currency

first time posting. Sorry if I mess up.

Essentially, code that will return **$2.00** if the value of the double is 2.0, but will return $.75 if the value of the double is .75 (instead of $0.75).

My issue is trying to figure out how to do this. I can use`formatter.format(price)` but that doesn't omit the leading 0. I can also try to do

```
String sPrice = String.valueOf(price);
sPrice = sPrice.replaceFirst("^0+", "");
```

but my issue with that is once I get to that point, I'm making more work for myself when I eventually call to return it, as I'd have to make it to add a 0 if there's only one number after the decimal point.

Here's my full code if you want to look through it, if it helps.

```
import java.text.*;

public class MenuItem
{
    private String name;
    private double price;
    private NumberFormat formatter = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();

    public MenuItem(String name, double price)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.price = price;
    }

    public String getName()
    {
        return name;
    }

    public double getPrice()
    {
        return price;
    }

    public String toString()
    {
        return name + " " + formatter.format(price);
    }

}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this,

*NumberFormat formatter = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();
formatter.setMinimumIntegerDigits(x);*

where x is number of digits you want.

Further more x can derive on demand depending on the input.

Answer (score 1):

Just try a simpler way

```
     double one = 0.75;
     double two = 2.00;

     System.out.println(String.format("$%.2f", one).replace("$0.", "$."));
     System.out.println(String.format("$%.2f", two).replace("$0.", "$."));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a simple custom `DecimalFormat` instead of the standard currency `NumberFormat`:

```
private static final DecimalFormat FORMAT = new DecimalFormat("$#.00");

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(FORMAT.format(0));
    System.out.println(FORMAT.format(0.01));
    System.out.println(FORMAT.format(0.75));
    System.out.println(FORMAT.format(1.2345));
    System.out.println(FORMAT.format(2.00));
    System.out.println(FORMAT.format(100.00));
}
```

Output:

> $.00
>   $.01
>   $.75
>   $1.23
>   $2.00
>   $100.00

### Update

Bohemian makes a good point in the comments that the solution above is very US-centric.  If you need to support a different locale, you can change the pattern to fit your locale.  But if you need to support multiple locales, the solution won't work very well.

In the case of multiple locales, I think I'd just stick with the default currency formatter returned by `NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(Locale)`.  If the leading zero absolutely must be removed in all locales, then [abo's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42824552/292728) (with x=0) should do the trick.  But I would caution against that, as there could be some locales where the leading zero is not optional, but mandatory.

Comment: definitely the better way

Comment: @scary as long as OP's locale (not specified) uses the dollar sign.

Answer (score 0):

you can simple substring in case of the `price < 1 && price >-1 && price != 0`

```
public String toString()
  {
        String priceString = formatter.format(price);

        if(price < 1 && price > -1 && price != 0)
            priceString = 0+ priceString;

      return name + " " + priceString;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a string problem, so use a string solution:

```
return name + " " + formatter.format(price).replaceAll("\\b0\\.", ".");
```

The `\\b` (word boundary) ensures you don't change `"$10.50"` to `"$1.50"`.